# How to test 'studio_view' in xblock-sdk?

Tags: edx, openedx

I'm developing a `custom-xblock`, where course-creator can add some html in predefined and pre-designed block.
I have installed `xblock-sdk` and using the same for xblock development.
I can test `student_view` in xblock-sdk but I want to test `studio_view` in the same environment.

Right now in forward to test studio_view, I have to install my developed custom-xblock in edx-platform.
If there is any way to test it in xblock-sdk then development can be faster and reliable.

I have `dogwood` release installed in `edx-devstack`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "test". If that's about manual testing - it is possible, but it is easier to just install it locally and check if it works in actual Studio. To access views other than `student_view`, just open scenario with an XBlock, than add `/${view_name}` to the URL - it should open that view (i.e. localhost:8080/scenario/test/student_view`)

If you're talking about unittests - read along.

There's xblock-utils repository that provides some quite useful base classes. One of those classes, [`SeleniumBaseTest`](https://github.com/edx/xblock-utils/blob/master/xblockutils/base_test.py#L118-174) might give you some insights on how to do that ([these lines in particular](https://github.com/edx/xblock-utils/blob/master/xblockutils/base_test.py#L169-170)).

Or you can just subclass your test class from it and use it (example: in [Poll XBlock tests](https://github.com/open-craft/xblock-poll/blob/bd93e4851c15d9cb1522e692f8b692cf584d23b1/tests/integration/test_studio.py#L50)). There's one possibly misleading/confusing thing about Studio views - there are two of them: 
* `studio_view` - is the view displayed when you click "edit" on a XBlock in a popup
* `author_view` - what's shown in unit. Usually defaults to `student_view` to show the same content to students and authors.

Note that full studio functionality won't be available there - some parts of it are external to block's `studio_view` and `author_view`, so they won't be there in sdk.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to test `Studio_view` on `XBlock-sdk`. The only way to test it is on devstack or fullstack. What I did is to update the custom XBlock whenever I change anything in it using this command: `sudo -u edxapp /edx/bin/pip.edxapp install --upgrade --no-deps yourXBlockFolder/`

Comment: Note that you can install the xblock in developer mode, instead of re-installing periodically, with: sudo -u edxapp /edx/bin/pip.edxapp install -e yourXBlockFolder/